# resize div container keeping every element horizontally align

Tags: html, css

I would create a page with all the elements aligned even if the user resize the page... unfortunately the code that I have written doesn't work correctly.

```
<div style="display:flex; justify-content: left; padding: 3px;">
<div style="margin:2px;">Language: <select name="lang"><option></option></select> | Pair language: </div>
<div style="margin:2px;"><select id="pairlang[]" name="pairlang[]" multiple size=3><option></option></select></div>
<div style="margin:2px;">Items: <input type="text" name="item" size="10">  | </div>
<div style="margin:2px;">Search: <input type="text" name="string"></div>
</div>
```

In the future it's possible that I will add new elements inside the div container... is there a way to keep all elements perfectly aligned even if resizing the width of the windows??

Comment: Even if the width becomes very small, they are still aligned horizontally?

Comment: You can use table

Comment: @Swellar the multiple select isn't perfectly aligned.

Comment: Can you show us an illustration of your desired result?

Comment: @Swellar This is the problem... https://ibb.co/iJY2i5

Comment: The multiple select is a plugin of JQuery

Answer (score 1):

Inline styling isn't the best choice. It is advised that you use CSS classes to define styling for better code management. Also it's best if you use `<label>` tags to specify the text/labels of the `<input>` or `<select>` elements.

You can achieve force horizontal alignment on child elements by adding `white-space:nowrap;` to the parent `<div>`; and by adding `display:inline-block;` to the child `<div>` tags. In case you want a horizontal scroll bar for the parent `<div>` then just add `overflow:x-scroll;` to the `.parent` class.

```css
.parent {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  // overflow-x: scroll;
  justify-content: left;
  padding: 3px;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  margin:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <label>Language:</label>
    <select name="lang">
      <option>English</option>
      <option>Hindi</option>
      <option>Persian</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <label>Pair language: </label>
    <select id="pairlang[]" name="pairlang[]" multiple size=3>
      <option>German</option>
      <option>Spanish</option>
      <option>French</option>
      <option>English</option>
      <option>Hindi</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <label>Items:</label>
    <input type="text" name="item" size="10" placeholder="3" />
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <label>Search:</label>
    <input type="text" name="string" placeholder="Enter search text here..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless the label and the input are align to each other instead of what OP has designed, I don't think this can help much.